# npm install just spins and blocks other internet use.

Tags: npm

I´ve discovered a weird issue with npm.

Whenever I run `npm install` the terminal marker just spins (forever) and all other internet use on my machine is blocked. If I abort with ctrl + C and run it again, it does not hang but I get a `npm WARN unmet dependency` for every dependency.

I´ve tried to reinstall npm but still get the same error.

I´m running OS X El Capitan.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could get a lot more info by running npm install with "--loglevel verbose" or "--loglevel silly" keys - please try these.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This *can* happen if npm dependencies get foobar'd. Please try to reset the whole npm package cache and reinstall:

```
$ rm -rf node_modules/
$ npm cache clean
$ sudo npm update -g npm
$ npm install
```

If it doesn't help, please run

```
$ npm install --loglevel verbose
```

and post your output.

Comment: Well, I´m amazed, this actually worked. Most likely the sudo npm update -g npm part that solved the issue, done the other ones a 100 times with no luck. Thank you!

Comment: @marsrover you're welcome. Can you please accept the answer if it worked for you? :)